# IE11 throw Invalid State error with this particular Blob construction

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, blob

I have this code to save an excel using Blob

```
//Stream of data as res
var dataView = new DataView(res);
var blob = new Blob([dataView], {type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel'});
```

But in IE only the third line throw Invalid State Error even though in the document, it is fully supported

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the issue pertains to IE. `Uint8Array` can be used in the constructor instead.

To convert a `DataView` to a equivalent `Uint8Array`:

```
var u8arr = new Uint8Array(dataView.buffer, dataView.byteOffset, dataView.byteLength);
```

Write a function to replace all `DataView` objects in the array passed to `new Blob`. Or see [the polyfill here](https://github.com/cshu/esrs/blob/master/polyfill.es.js#L1).